# Looking for Coleman's paper "The Gross-Koblitz formula"

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, paper-request

I am looking for a copy of the following paper by Robert Coleman:

The Gross-Koblitz formula. 
Galois representations and arithmetic algebraic geometry 
(Kyoto, 1985/Tokyo, 1986), 21–52,
Adv. Stud. Pure Math., 12, North-Holland, Amsterdam, 1987.

I've done a exhaustive search on the internet with no results. There is a web page http://mathsoc.jp/publication/ASPM/ of the "Advanced Studies in Pure Mathematics", and they have some of their issues online, but not the volume in which Coleman's paper appears.

Does anyone have a copy of this article?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**: To avoid any titles confusion, I mention here that there is another (pretty well-known) book called "Galois representations ***in*** arithmetic algebraic geometry".

Comment: Dear @j.c. I've already searched there and I found  "Galois representations IN arithmetic algebraic geometry" which is not the same proceedings volume.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct; I deleted my comment.

Comment: Have you tried looking at university library catalogs to see where the whole book (not simply the article) is available?  For example, there is a copy of the book in the libraries of Harvard (http://id.lib.harvard.edu/aleph/001464111/catalog), Princeton (https://pulsearch.princeton.edu/catalog/SCSB-6024148), Univ. Chicago (http://pi.lib.uchicago.edu/1001/cat/bib/996220), and that's not an exhaustive list. You could try to request the book by interlibrary loan, or request a scan of the article from those libraries through your own university library. (I also have my own marked-up copy.)

Comment: Der @KConrad. I thought about asking in my university if they could get me a copy from other libraries, but the thing is that it is impossible until march, since in Chile the summer vacations start now (and end at the beginnings of march), and they close everything, incluiding libraries. Would you share your marked-up copy? I'm sure your notes are going to help me a lot :)

Comment: Okay, I have now scanned my copy of the paper.  Coleman had once given me errata sheets for the paper, and my markings in the paper are for the most part those corrections.  Coleman's errata sheets are at the end of the scan, for completeness. Please email me and I'll send you the scan.